# Show only week days no next prev months years and days

Tags: jquery, calendar, days, timetable

I am using [jquery-week-calendar](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki). Its integrated without any issue but now my requirement is to only use "Week Days" not month and year with next previous options.

I want to have week days only i.e "Monday, Tuesday,... Sunday" on the top side and "hours" on the left side.

So when I click on any slot to enter my todo I just only see Hour and day.

This is the demo [url](http://robmonie.github.io/jquery-week-calendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html).

Thanks.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far

Comment: @kyriacos_k I have checked complete document but there does not seems to be any solution, can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Can its ok to hide them with CSS. If yes then you can hide those controls via following code:

```
.wc-nav{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: No this cant help me because when the week changes calendar automatically will move to next week and my saved data will not be visible on that. Also when showing calendar I have data and that data is passed with dates as well like this [{"start":"Tue Nov 03 2015 15:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)","end":"Tue Nov 03 2015 16:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)","id":"10","title":"test","body":"test"}]